# how to compute ideal scales and aspect ratios for faster rcnn network model training in object detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I have a sizable dataset (50k images + pascal voc xml files ). I am trying to train my model with tensorflow faster rcnn algo. Since scales and aspect ratios should be inline with dataset I tried to create an algo for computing the ideal values. Since the docs are scarce about how to arrive at scale and aspect ratios, I need some help with confirming if this kmeans clustering algo is accurate.

Here is the algo I am using

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def compute_scales_and_aspect_ratios(directory, n_clusters, img_size):
    widths = []
    heights = []

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
        fullname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        tree = ET.parse(fullname)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for obj in root.iter('object'):
            xmlbox = obj.find('bndbox')
            w = float(xmlbox.find('xmax').text) - float(xmlbox.find('xmin').text)
            h = float(xmlbox.find('ymax').text) - float(xmlbox.find('ymin').text)
            widths.append(w)
            heights.append(h)

    widths = np.array(widths) / img_size[1]  # Normalize by image width
    heights = np.array(heights) / img_size[0]  # Normalize by image height

    scales = np.sqrt(widths * heights).reshape(-1, 1)
    aspect_ratios = (widths / heights).reshape(-1, 1)

    kmeans_scales = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=0).fit(scales)
    kmeans_aspect_ratios = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=0).fit(aspect_ratios)

    return kmeans_scales.cluster_centers_, kmeans_aspect_ratios.cluster_centers_

directory = "path_to_top_folder/batch-1"
n_clusters = 5  # Change this to the number of clusters you want
img_size = (640, 1024)  # Change this to your standard image size (height, width)
scales, aspect_ratios = compute_scales_and_aspect_ratios(directory, n_clusters, img_size)

print('Scales:', scales.flatten())
print('Aspect Ratios:', aspect_ratios.flatten())
```